# codeigniter database query

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, field

Is it possible to write this query in codeigniter active records?

```
$Main_Nav_Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kategorie WHERE nadrad = 0 order by poradie;");
```

Because I found this code to create menu with sub fields, and I want to change it to codeigniter code, and also add there some possibility to have unlimited submenus for example

```
Menu1
     Menu 1 1
     Menu 1 2
     Menu 1 3
             Menu 1 3 1
             Menu 1 3 2
             Menu 1 3 3
                       Menu 1 3 3 1
Menu 2
Menu 3
```

etc.

here is full code:

```
$Main_Nav_Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kategorie WHERE nadrad = 0 order by poradie;");    //Query for the main items

    echo "<ul id=\"navigation-list\">\n";
    //Main items
    while($Main_Nav_Query_Results = mysql_fetch_array($Main_Nav_Query)) {
        //Set main data
        $Main_Nav_ID         = $Main_Nav_Query_Results['id'];
        $Main_Nav_Name         = $Main_Nav_Query_Results['nazov'];
        $Main_Nav_Link        = $Main_Nav_Query_Results['menu'];
        $Main_Nav_Parent    = $Main_Nav_Query_Results['nadrad'];

        //Create the list items for each main level
        echo "\t\t\t\t<li class=\"mainlevel\" id=\"\"><a >$Main_Nav_Name</a>";

            //Sub items
            $Sub_Nav_Query     = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kategorie WHERE nadrad = '$Main_Nav_ID';");    //Query for the sub items
            while($Sub_Nav_Query_Results = mysql_fetch_array($Sub_Nav_Query)) {
                //Set Sub data
                $Sub_Nav_ID         = $Sub_Nav_Query_Results['id'];
                $Sub_Nav_Name         = $Sub_Nav_Query_Results['nazov'];
                $Sub_Nav_Link        = $Sub_Nav_Query_Results['menu'];
                $Sub_Nav_Parent        = $Sub_Nav_Query_Results['nadrad'];

                //Create the markup for the sub items (list items)
                $Sub_List = "<li class=\"sub-item\"><a >$Sub_Nav_Name</a></li>";    

                //Check if the current item has any sub items
                if($Sub_Nav_Parent == $Main_Nav_ID) {
                        echo "<ul class=\"sub-list\">";
                        echo "$Sub_List";
                        echo "</ul>";                    
                }                            
            }        
        echo "</li>\n";    //Close the sub items
    }
    echo "\t\t\t</ul>\n";        //Close the unordered list for the main items
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: To add submenus or children, you will have to deal with either Nested Sets: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model , Tree Traversal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal or other model

Comment: why aren't you using the active record class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$this->db->where('nadrad', 0);
$this->db->order_by('poradie', 'ASC');
$rows = $this->db->get('kategorie')->result();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $Main_Nav_ID = $row->id;
    //etc..
}
```

Comment: Its not working, I have already tried it, it returns error:
`A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given`

Comment: You don't use `mysql_fetch_array()` to get the data from the active record results. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, it works well, and is it possible to edit it, to create multi levels menu? for example submenu for existing submenu?

Comment: I recommend adding submenus from a different table using a second query.

Comment: But problem is, that i am connecting to existing project, so there is a lot of menu items and subitems existing in this one table

Comment: This is out of the scope of this question. I recommend opening a new question, more specific regarding the sub menus. The way they are organized now and how they should be organized. Please add only the relevant code.